# How can I boot Ubuntu from a USB?

Tags: 12.10, windows-8

I bought a Compaq pc with Windows 8 a few months ago and now I want to install Ubuntu but still keep Windows 8. I tried Webi but when my pc restarts it read ERROR 0x000007b. I know that Windows 8 has a thing about not letting you have Ubuntu but I still want to have both OS without actually losing all my data. How can I do this?

Comment: I have Ubuntu 12.10 in a USB and I'm trying to boot it from my USB

Comment: Are you asking how to boot Ubuntu, or how to install it to your hard disk once you've booted an Ubuntu live USB? It seems likely [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system) will help you, but beyond that, you'll probably have to provide some clarification, to get an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I can´t say much about Wubi but how did you create your Live-USB? I had Problems with LiLu and Pendrive, try to create the live-usb with [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) if it still doesn´t work try to disable [fast startup](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3152/~/disable-windows-8-fast-startup-%28hibernate-file%29) in Windows8.